# Mapping Network Device Went Wrong

Tags: windows-7, networking

The main problem is that I cannot connect to shared folders in my own network

I accidentally tried to map network drive under my Network options and as there was no letter of hard disks I use (I use C: and I:) I clicked Z:

Now I can't access my own shared folders from file explorer, it shows that \My-PC is not accessible and prints out that Specific Network Providers Name Is Invalid

My brother from other PC can access my shared folders and everything works for him. Also i can ping PC both ways.

I'm running Win7 64-bit

Here are some steps:

[image]

Then I selected letter Z: but I don't have any drive named Z: so there started this problem:

[image]

I suppose I need to change back the letter of the drive, but I cant find a way to do that.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to make it more readable and understandable. What version of Windows are you running? What are the exact steps you are following? What is the exact message appearing? Does your computer believe it's on a private network? Does your Firewall like blocking things such as file sharing?

Answer (score 0):

**Right** **click** the Drive and Hit **Disconnect**.

Now set it to the correct path below.

To connect to a **Shared folder** do this.

1Open My Network Places. To do so, click **Start**, click **My Computer**, and then click **My Network Place**s under Other Places. Or, start Windows Explorer, and then click **My Network Places**.

2.Click **Entire Network**.

3.Double-click **Microsoft Windows Network**, and then double-click **DomainName**, where DomainName is the name of your domain.

4.Double-click **ComputerName**, where ComputerName is the name of the computer that contains the files that you want to access.

5.A list of shared folders and printers on that computer is displayed.
Double-click the shared folder to which you want to gain access.

Comment: On which Win version are you working cause no steps can be done in Win7. As I said i have to reverse that mapping. And i noticed that i cant add shared folders. Because PC cant find that path.

Comment: Was working on windows 7 enterprise was at work.

Comment: Maybe you want to help out with TeamViewer?